# (eclipse) transfering java files from other projects into another src file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm pretty new to coding, and did a little 'fun' programming over summer. We used eclipse to write our projects- after which i saved it on a flash drive. The flash drive didn't quite worked as planned and long story short I have the code that I wrote but its not in the src or java projects. How so I transfer these java files into an src from a new project?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help you to import all your Java files to new project SRC folder :

1 - Create new JAVA Project

2 - Do right click on project and click on Import

3 - Select option called : General -> File System

4 - Select you Java files from your local drive and Click on Finish